# Emacs regexp to increment/decrement array indices

Tags: c, arrays, emacs, indexing

Is it possible to use a regular expression to alter an array index in emacs?

e.g. for some C code change:

```
int my_array[4];
my_array[0] = 1;
my_array[1] = 2;
my_array[2] = 3;
```

to:

```
int my_array[4];
my_array[1] = 1;
my_array[2] = 2;
my_array[3] = 3;
```

a sort of replace `[i]` with `[i+1]` operation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
   M-x query-replace-regexp my_array\[\([0-9]+\)\] RET my_array[\,(1+ \#1)]
```

\, in replacement string can be replaced by any lisp expression.

(last edit: using `\#1` in place of `(string-to-int \1)`)

Comment: works like a charm, I pared it down to:<kbd>M-x</kbd>  `query-replace-regexp`  `\[\([0-9]+\)\]`  `[\,(1+ (string-to-int \1))]`  to incrementally step through all arrays. many thanks

Comment: You can just say `\#1` instead of `(string-to-int \1)`.

Comment: to decrement the array index use - M-x query-replace-regexp my_array\[\([0-9]+\)\] RET my_array[\,(1- \#1)]

Comment: interesting - what if you have no array name before the []?, and you want to decrement rather than increment, e.g. turn [1] into [0] (the [1] being the only text in the line of interest?

Comment: also whats with the "" in re-builder?

Comment: i'm getting an invalid use of \ in replacement text

Comment: in other words, if you ditch the my_array bit then it stops working

Comment: `M-x query-replace-regexp \[\([0-9]+\)\] RET [\,(1+ \#1)]` is working! and the function thad decrement is `1-`.

Comment: Remi you are the emacs man! - not sure why i couldn't get it to work, must have been a misplaced \ somewhere - all fine now..

Comment: Oh dear - having another problem with this - if i want to increment by something other than 1, say 52 i try this [\,(52+ \#1)] but get a 'Symbol's function definition is void: 52+' and it doesn't do anything

Comment: ok fixed with [\,(+ 52 \#1)] - how did the original work with an infix rather than prefix operator?

Comment: There is no infix operator, you should read the error message: it tell you that the function definition is void for 52+. 1+ and 1- are Emacs lisp function, but 52+ is undefined, You could define it, but it not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

increment:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \[\([0-9]+\)\] RET [\,(1+ \#1)]
```

decrement:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \[\([0-9]+\)\] RET [\,(1- \#1)]
```